# Magento error message: 'Failed to find .../template.less'

Tags: magento

I bought a Magento theme, I tried to install 5 times without success, I followed the step-by-step documentation. Whenever I activate the theme I get this message:

`load error: failed to find /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/garden/skin/frontend/gardenwares/default/less/template.less` .

The theme is uploaded to the server, locally I have the same message, I tried it on another server, same error, I wonder what I can do to fix it.

```
Trace:
#0 /home/hoadecob/public_html/lib/Cmsmart/Less.php(1797): lessc->compileFile('/opt/bitnami/ap...')
#1 /home/hoadecob/public_html/lib/Cmsmart/Less.php(93): lessc->cachedCompile(Array)
#2 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/design/frontend/gardenwares/default/template/page/html/head.phtml(89): lessc->autoCompileLess(Object(lessc), '/home/hoadecob/...', '/home/hoadecob/...')
#3 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/hoadecob/...')
#4 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/garden...')
#5 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#6 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#9 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/design/frontend/gardenwares/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(9): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#10 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/hoadecob/...')
#11 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/garden...')
#12 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#16 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#17 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#18 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#19 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#20 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#21 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 /home/hoadecob/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 /home/hoadecob/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#25 {main}
```

[image]

Comment: the more than obvious question: is the file in that location: did you double check it?

Comment: Fabio thanks for your answer, i edited my post (thanks you corrected the grammar), i'm from france . Look the current directory, is it correct right ? Is it this file ?

Comment: well, your image is not the same as your stack trace since one seems to be for a local machine and the other for a server, but assuming you're replicating your local version in a server, it doesn't seem to be the same by any means

Comment: For this test, I'm working on an online server. I uploaded the theme I bought via Magento Connect and this should work but it's not the case. I don't know why there is /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/garden/

Comment: i didn't replicate my local version in a server ... it's really weird ...

Comment: no, wait, my bad, your file is correct, but it's trying to find something somewhere else, as if you needed to edit some file location to replace that /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs part. Are you sure you didn't forgot to replace something if this is an automatic upload? If not, can you try to upload the files by yourself and see if the issue persist?

Comment: I tried to upload the files without going through Magento connect, and I have the same error, I'm tired, I hope someone can find me the solution ^^ What can I do? Thank you for your help.

Comment: any idea ? :( please

Comment: guys please i need help ;)

Comment: Just posted the fix as answer @user3790914

Answer (score 0):

The idiot developers of the theme left their LESS cache included with the packaged download so when you install it, it looks in the absolute server root for their server so subsequently can't find any files when someone installs it on their own server.

Simple fix is to navigate to the following path:-

```
/skin/frontend/theme_name/default/less
```

And simply delete the file `template.less.cache`.

Force refresh the frontend in your browser and you should find it then loads...